# finding a probability density function of a random variable given a relation between another random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to find a pdf for a random variable $X$ where $X=-2Y+1$ and $Y$ is given by $N(4,9)$

Here is my attempt:

we know $\mu=4$ and $\sigma=3$. so that the normal distribution of $Y$ is given by $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(y-4)^2}{18}$
We can differentiate the cumulative function of $X$ to get the pdf for $X$.
cdf of $X = P(X<x)$ = $P(-2Y+1<x)=P(Y<\frac{-(x-1)}{2})=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{-(x-1)}{2}}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(y-4)^2}{18}dy$
so $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{-(x-1)}{2}}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(y-4)^2}{18}dy)=f(x)$, which is the density function for $X$
$f(x)=-\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(\frac{-(x-1)}{2}-4)^2}{18}$

Is this a correct way to approach the problem? I feel like my answer is very funky.

Comment: Check your calculations once again. Remember, $$ -2Y + 1 < x~\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad Y >\frac{-(x-1)}{2}$$ You've written the opposite inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote distribution functions by $F$, and density functions by $f$. Then,
\begin{align*}
F_X(x) &= P(X \leqslant x)\\
&= P\left(Y \geqslant \frac{1-x}{2}\right)\\
&= 1 - F_Y\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\\
&= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{1-x}{2}} f_Y(t) dt\\
&= 1 - \int_{0}^{\frac{1-x}{2}} f_Y(t) dt - \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_Y(t) dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \int_{0}^{\frac{1-x}{2}} f_Y(t) dt
\end{align*}
Therefore, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have : $$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot f_Y\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left[-\frac{(x+7)^2}{72}\right]$$
So, $~X \sim N(-7,36)$ . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$-2Y+1 <x$ is not equivalent to $Y <-\frac {x-1} 2$.

$P(X\leq x)=P(-2Y+1 \leq x)=P(Y \geq \frac {1-x} 2)=\int_{\frac  {1 -x} 2}^{\infty} \phi (t)dt$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal density. Hence the density of $X$ is $\frac 1 2\phi (\frac {1-x} 2)$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one may use the very well known (and easy) fact that

> If $S \sim N(0,1)$ , then $T = aS + b \sim N(b , a^2)$ .

Here, as $Y \sim N(4,9)$ , so $Y = 3S + 4$ . Therefore, $$X = -2Y +1 = -2(3S + 4) + 1 = -6S - 7$$ Thus, $X \sim N(-7 , 36)$ .